# Browser is caching AngularJS views when used with ASP .NET MVC4 & IIS6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I'm using AngularJS on client side and ASP .NET MVC4 as a framework. Application is hosted on IIS6. Unfortunately after each release I get feedback that some pages don't work. I turned out that AngularJS requests for views, eg.

```
/AppName/Home/Index
```

are returning 304 status code (I have no idea why...) and browser is using old template. Only hard refresh (ctrl + f5) helps.

Is there a way to configure IIS6 or ASP .NET MVC4 or change web.config in order to prevent browser from caching the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to mark actions for views that you dont want to cache with [OutputCache attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) like this:

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```

It will disable MVC lavel cache. After that browser can still keep some cache. To prevent this try to use something like [this](http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/2011/07/29/disable-browser-cache-in-asp-mvc/).